# jQuery onclick not working iOS 10 <a> Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios

I've got a slow loading link on a page so I wrote the below javascript that triggers a loading message. The problem is its not working on mobile devices. I've tried using touchstart touch etc but when the link is tapped it triggers the loading screen but does not load the URL. I've also tried adding style="cursor:pointer;" to the  with no success.

An example link would be:

```
<a href="http://google.com">Example Link</a>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").on('click', function () {
     $('add stuff to js body').prependTo(document.body);
  });
});
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sgpaxhfh/)

Comment: Try `$("a").on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('add stuff to js body').prependTo(document.body);
});
`

Comment: @Rayon Thanks for the reply, thats causing the same behaviour as touchstart the loading screen displays but the link is not loaded.

Comment: Could you share a fiddle ?

Comment: @Rayon I've updated the post to include a JSFiddle of the issue

Comment: You still have to prevent redirection right ?

Comment: @Rayon I need it to redirect to the link once its loaded. On a desktop the above displays a loading message while the link loads(its doing php database processing) then displays the page when its loaded. On mobile it doesn't trigger the link and just displaying loading when either your code or touchstart is added. I know its something silly causing this but its driving me made lol Thanks

Comment: try changing the url to `http://google.com&output=embed`

Comment: @Danoram Didn't make any difference but thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code.I hope it will help you.

```
<a href="http://google.com">Example Link</a>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do your stuff
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  });
});
</script>
```

Thank You.